# Upload Files to Parse backend using Rest API

Tags: http, parse-platform, upload, httprequest

Im trying to upload some images and sound files to my parse server however....  I am at a complete loss of how to do this.

The documentation here: https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#files
is just beyond me on how to begin uploading files.

there is a blog post :
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/file-uploading-via-rest-api/

```
curl -X POST 
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" 
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}"     
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" 
  -T 'hello.txt' 
  https://api.parse.com/1/files/hello.txt
```

but this doesn't mean anything to me.  the documentation is assuming some level of understanding that i do not have.

surely this is a pretty common task?

Comment: curl is a command to issue http requests. conduct a minimal research before posting and let us know if you're having any troubles.

Comment: Ive been playing around with postman and can't get a valid response for the https://api.parse.com and can not figure out how to input the command as shown above correctly for anything to happen.  prefixing a standard http request with curl just returns "Could not get any response"

Comment: parse.com no longer exists. you need to target your server (localhost if developing locally). perhaps you should do some reading regarding APIs and how to consume them.